# Eliminar valor de um dicionário em Python

Tags: python, dicionário

Preciso de eliminar uma key de um dicionário se determinada situação se verificar.
Tenho este código:

```
for i in dict.keys(dataClean):
     dataClean[i] = dataClean[i] - 1
     if dataClean[i] == 0:
          del dict.keys(dataClean[i]) # remover i do dataClean
```

Mas a ultima linha não funciona desse jeito. Como deve ser feito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover um valor do dicionário, ele não é feito da forma que estava tentando realizar:

```
del dict.keys(dataClean[i]) # remover i do dataClean
```

Ele é realizado desta forma:

```
del dataClean[i]
```

Porém, realizar uma remoção de um iterável durante sua execução, apresentará a seguinte o seguinte erro:

```
File ".../del-dict-element.py", line 11, in <module>
for i in dict.keys(dataClean):
```

Seguido de sua excessão:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

O `Python` tem uma funcionalidade que remove o item desejado, o `pop()`:

```
dictionary.pop(keyname, defaultvalue)
```

Porém, segue uma versão intuitiva para seu código:

```
dicionario = {
    'dois': 2,
    'tres': 3,
    'quatro': 4,
    'cinco': 5,
    'seis': 6,
    'sete': 7,
    'baguncado': 1,
    'outro baguncado': 1
}

remover_itens = []

for chave, valor in dicionario.items():
    dicionario[chave] = dicionario[chave] -1
    if dicionario[chave] == 0:
        remover_itens.append(chave)

for item in remover_itens:
    dicionario.pop(item)

print(dicionario)
```

input: `{'dois': 1, 'tres': 2, 'quatro': 3, 'cinco': 4, 'seis': 5, 'sete': 6, 'baguncado': 0, 'outro baguncado': 0}`

output: `{'dois': 1, 'tres': 2, 'quatro': 3, 'cinco': 4, 'seis': 5, 'sete': 6}`

Answer (score 2):

Não é uma boa ideia remover chaves de um iterável enquanto você percorre ele, use compreensão de lista para esse caso.
Exemplo:

```
dic = {
    'a': 13,
    'b': 0,
    'c': 52,
    'd': 0,
    'e': 0,
    'f': 79
}

newDic = { key: dic[key] for key in dic if dic[key] != 0 }

print(newDic)
# {'a': 13, 'c': 52, 'f': 79}
```